# Creating custom transformer with sklearn - missing required positional argument error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a custom transformer that will split a column into multiple columns and I want to provide the delimiter also.

Here is the code I made to create the transformer

```
class StringSplitTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def __init__(self, cols = None):
    self.cols = cols
def transform(self,df,delim):
    X = df.copy()
    for col in self.cols:
        X = pd.concat([X,X[col].str.split(delim,expand = True)], axis = 1)
    return X
def fit(self, *_):
    return self
```

When I run `fit()` and `transform()` separately, it all works fine:

```
split_trans = StringSplitTransformer(cols = ['Cabin'])
split_trans.fit(df)
split_trans.transform(df, '/')
```

But when I run `fit_transform()` it give me an error:

```
split_trans.fit_transform(X_train, '/')

TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'delim'
```

In my `transform()` function if I don't have the `delim` parameter and instead just provide the delimiter then `fit_transform()` works.
I don't understand why it does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fit` should accept at least two arguments, positional `X` and optional `y=None`. When you call `fit_transform`, your transformer assigns `y='\'` and misses `delim`. Well, I would rather make `delim` an attribute:

```py
class StringSplitTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, delim, cols=None):
        self.delim = delim
        self.cols = cols

    def fit(self, df, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, df):
        X = df.copy()
        for col in self.cols:
            X = pd.concat([X, X[col].str.split(self.delim, expand=True)],
                          axis=1)
        return X
```